# I am trying to make my text box the same height as my submit button but website ignoring CSS

Tags: html, css, textbox

http://www.wecare.bz
Where you enter your post code, the text box and button are aligned but the text box is slimmer than the submit button and the css isn't taking my height overide which is stupidly large"

My HTML

```
<form class="pcm" action="/index.php/bridge" method="POST">
<div><input class="pcmtext" name="postcode" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Postcode..." /> <input class="pcmbutton" type="submit" value="Get Started today!" />
```

My CSS

```
.pcmtext {
  width:25%;
  height:500px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.pcmbutton {
  width:40%;
  height:500px;
  vertical-align: top
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky to spot, but the `input[type="text"]` selector in joomla.css is more specific that your `.pcmtext`, so it wins and sets `height:46px;`.

All you need to do is make your selector more specific, probably `input.pcmtext` makes most sense. Then your override will kick in:

```
.pcmtext {
  width:25%;
  height:500px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Works very well! Next issue is doing the same with the submit button though!

Answer (score 0):

rules in CSS have weights, You can read more about it in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Now in Your case, target `.imageBg #gkHeaderMod input[type="submit"]` has more specificity than `.pcmbutton`, so in overriding You should use more specific target, like: `.imageBg #gkHeaderMod .pcmbutton` or `.imageBg #gkHeaderMod input[type="submit"].pcmbutton`